# How to create folders in external SD Card on Android 4.4.2?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I've added the permissions to read and write in the manifest file.
By default my device has the following folders:

/storage/emulated/0

/storage/emulated/legacy

/storage/sdcard0

/storage/sdcard1

/storage/usbcard1

It turns out that is not being can create folders in /storage/sdcard1, which is the location of the sdcard, with the same method I can create folders in /storage/emulated/0.

**This is my method to create folders**

```
private static boolean CriarDiretorio(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) return true;  // already exists
    if (dir.exists()) return false;      // already exists, but is not a directory
    return dir.mkdirs();                 // create it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot read or write in arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 4.4+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

You are welcome to call `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note: plural). If it returns 2+ directories, the second and subsequent ones will be directories on removable storage, unique for your app, that you can can read from and write to.

Comment: I tried to use the method in the code below but still could not create a new folder.


'File[] ext = _context.getExternalFilesDirs("/storage/sdcard1/newfolder");
Boolean created = ext[0].mkdirs();'

Comment: @RenanViníciusQuadrosBarbosa: First, `ext[0]` will point to a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Second, the parameter to `getExternalFilesDirs()` is not a path. You may wish to review [the documentation for `getExternalFilesDirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Got it. Would you have any examples of using getExternalFilesDirs (String type)?

Comment: @RenanViníciusQuadrosBarbosa: Not handy, as I tend to avoid using removable storage. And, for `getExternalFilesDir()` (the singular), I just pass `null` as a parameter.

Comment: If we can't create folder , then how apps like ES File explorer are creating in my 4.4.2 phone without root access.? Can you explain @CommonsWare

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: Presumably, they are using the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: You mean it's possible to work with Storage Access Framework (Basic operations like copy, create new etc.) without even opening Documents screen? If is it so, Can you please provide a way to achieve?

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal: My understanding is that tools like ES use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` on Android 5.0+ to "grant permissions to work with the SD card". From there, `DocumentFile` allows you to traverse the document hierarchy, create new documents, etc. That is not available on Android 4.4, and I have no idea what ES might be doing there, other than perhaps exploiting some security flaw.

Comment: Thanx, I will look into 5.0+,  how `DocumentFile` works .But in 4.4.2 ES File explorer is  accessing everything normally, don't know how, will look into it.Anyways thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to root the OS first, then use root explorer. Or to create a folder and the documents with one of those 3rd party file managers to write on in the internal memory card and when finished writing the documents and creating folders, then use the internal file manager that came with Kitkat OS to then copy the created folder and documents to the external SD card. For now this is the only way until a amazing programmer hacker can fix the problem.